# How to run a Python script without the Python application showing up?

Tags: python, macos

I wrote a Python script that includes some libraries like Cocoa, Quartz, AppKit. When I run this, the Python application (lava lamp with Python icon) shows up in the dock. How can I run a script without that showing up? I'd like to leave the script open while I work, for measuring what I am working on.

[image]

Comment: It's a rocket not a lava lamp!

Answer (score 0):

[py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) would be one way to do that.  I'm not sure the meaning of your last sentence.

Comment: I think i get it, he just wants the app open while he's working on other things.  My guess is that his app is performing background tasks...etc and he doesn't want to clutter up his dock, or he's tracking keystrokes ;)!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`python my_script.py &`